# Do I need admin access to work with certificates?

Tags: c#, certificate, admin

Do the users need admin privileges in order to work with certificates?  For example, if I am a non-admin user, when I run some code to store certificates, will I get any problems?

I see that the enumeration StoreName has a number of enum values, and one of them is My.  I wonder if using StoreName.My allows my code to work for both admin and non-admin users.

Thank you.

Comment: Which product or programming language are you talk about? Improve your question to get a answer.

Comment: I am working with C#.

Comment: This is not necessarily related to programming languages, but it is relevant to mention that you are working on windows although it can be seen from your question.

Comment: I would agree that your question can hardly be answered unless you provide substantially more details. But I have tried to comment below.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with certificates as a standard user, but you probably want to achieve something with the certificates, that cannot be done as a non-admin.

As you correctly hint you can access two store: My (Personal in the mmc plugin) and Machine.

You can do everything in My, and you can read all certs public keys in Machine. If you want to install a certificate for the IIS worker processes, you will have to do it in Machine store. And this will require you to be an admin.

You should also be aware that most encryption-related tasks will require that the process can read the certificates private key. In these cases the cert should be installed in Machine/Personal and the correct process should be granted private key access afterwards.